# Sql2000 replicate for xml path('')

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, coalesce, for-xml-path

I am trying to replicate the following code in SQL 2000 which does not have FOR XML PATH('').

```
select '"Footer",' +  stuff((SELECT ',' + '"' + server + '"'
FROM servers
FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
```

The output is -

```
 "Footer","MyServer1","MyServer2","MyServer3"
```

The closest I can get is with the code below but the output is missing the inverted commas around each server name.

```
declare @result varchar(max)

select @result = COALESCE(@result + ', ', '') + server
                from servers

select '"Footer",' + @result
```

The output is -

```
"Footer",MyServer1,MyServer2,MyServer3
```

Comment: Why are you using unsupported software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the quotes in the expression:

```
declare @result varchar(max);

select @result = COALESCE(@result + ', ', '') + '"' + server + '"'
from servers;

select '"Footer",' + @result;
```